# Always add trailing slash application-wide

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

I want to serve my Ember application ALWAYS with trailing-slashes. That also means that any route accessed like `myapp.com/cool-page` would be rewritten/redirect to as `myapp.com/cool-page`.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better do add a trailing slash via your server settings, not sure what you are using, but have a look at [this](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/) if you're using apache.

It should be possible to add the slash with Ember, but the problem is that it will first load your app, then it will observe that there is no slash so it will redirect with a slash causing your app to reload.

When handling it with a mod rewrite as described above, the URL will be captured before loading the ember app.